# Import a Justinmind prototype into a website

Tags: html, prototype, justinmind

I have little experience with coding since I am currently working as a business analyst, but I have been presented with the challenge of making a website that holds all the information about a project, and that can be just zipped up and distributed to all the third parties involved. That sets some specific limitations like not being able to count with a server. Whoever is going to use this site must be able to do it by unzipping and opening Index.html

That being said, one of the reasons why we need to document using a website is because the project is mainly UX and Design and is full of prototypes.

Now, I am using the following in order to include those prototypes in my web structure:

```
`<div class="prototype">
     <iframe src="Documentation/Prototypes/Search/html5/index.html" width="100%" height="1024px"></iframe>
 </div>`
```

But it is not working for the ones I export from Justinmind, yet it works perfectly with the ones from scketchapp. When I do this with a proto from JiM, it just display the wrapper box from "prototype" without content.

Could you please help me? I am falling in despair over here! Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

if it's of any help to anybody else, the problen is Chrome, which is where I was visualizing my work. It's properly imported in FF and IE